# security vulnerability in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, sql-injection

I wrote a small Spring MVC application - Security vulnerability scanning shows SQL Injection. Please let me know where is the issue and how we can fix.

Below is my JSP and java code.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/app/save.html">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="id">Employee ID:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="id" value="${employee.id}"
                    readonly="true" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Employee Name:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" value="${employee.name}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="age">Employee Age:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="age" value="${employee.age}" /></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td><form:label path="salary">Employee Salary:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="salary" value="${employee.salary}" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="address">Employee Address:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="address" value="${employee.address}" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

<c:if test="${!empty employees}">
    <h2>List Employees</h2>
    <table align="left" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Age</th>
            <th>Employee Salary</th>
            <th>Employee Address</th>
            <th>Actions on Row</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.age}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.salary}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.address}" /></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="edit.html?id=${employee.id}">Edit</a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Controller file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean
    , BindingResult result) {
    Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
    employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/add.html");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean
    , BindingResult result) {
    Map < String, Object > model = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
    model.put("employees", prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
    return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
}


private Employee prepareModel(EmployeeBean employeeBean) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEmpAddress(employeeBean.getAddress());
    employee.setEmpAge(employeeBean.getAge());
    employee.setEmpName(employeeBean.getName());
    employee.setSalary(employeeBean.getSalary());
    employee.setEmpId(employeeBean.getId());
    employeeBean.setId(null);
    return employee;
}

private List < EmployeeBean > prepareListofBean(List < Employee > employees) {
    List < EmployeeBean > beans = null;
    if (employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()) {
        beans = new ArrayList < EmployeeBean > ();
        EmployeeBean bean = null;
        for (Employee employee: employees) {
            bean = new EmployeeBean();
            bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
            bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
            bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
            bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
            bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
            beans.add(bean);
        }
    }
    return beans;
}

private EmployeeBean prepareEmployeeBean(Employee employee) {
    EmployeeBean bean = new EmployeeBean();
    bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
    bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
    bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
    bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
    bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
    return bean;
}
```

DAO Implementation

```
@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .saveOrUpdate(employee);
    }
```

Model Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479 L; {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "empid")
        private Integer empId;

        @Column(name = "empname")
        private String empName;

        @Column(name = "empaddress")
        private String empAddress;

        @Column(name = "salary")
        private Long salary;

        @Column(name = "empAge")
        private Integer empAge;
    }
}
```

Comment: is your DAO contains only this(`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .saveOrUpdate(employee);` or any native queries??

Comment: I don't know Spring enough, but this code doesn't look obviously vulnerable to SQL injection to me. Note that static source code scanners are far from perfect, sometimes they infer an application is vulnerable, when in fact it is not.

Comment: @Sam thanks for your response. No other native methods. I am just using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() .saveOrUpdate(employee); to save model data in DB table.

Comment: Can you expand upon what the security vulnerability scanning is actually doing? How does it test, what does it say? Do you know it's not a false positive?

Comment: @Kings I think saveOrUpdate is `sql Injection Safe`.

Comment: @andrel -- Following is the advisory Application Specific Vulnerability 

WASC Threat Classification
SQL Injection 

Security Risk

It is possible to view, modify or delete database entries and tables


Possible Causes

Sanitation of hazardous characters was not performed correctly on user input


CVE Reference(s)
N/A

CWE Reference(s)
89